# Nuxt.js force ssr after hydration

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, hydration

Given I had to use a module which calls `fs` and modifies my asyncData, I would have to implement it in a way that forces it to run on the server.

```
asyncData() {
    return {foo: 'bar'}
},
something() {  //what do I use?
    const mymodule=require('mymodule') //uses server modules
    this.foo = mymodule(this.foo)
}
```

How do I achieve that? Is it possible to force asyncData to be called on the server only after hydration?

Comment: Not quite understand what you mean, but asyncdata executed on server on initial load, so you will effectively fisable client did navogation and that page will be rendered on server, e.g. don't use nuxt-link touter.push etc

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is if it's possible to send bundled data with the .js module/file to the client after hydration? (instead of then fetching the data on the client)

Comment: only whole page on access. What u are describing is an api u want to access